# Reading a JSON file in NodeJs

Tags: json, node.js

I have a small JSON file with this content

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1593,
      "name": "Foo Bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to read this content by using the filesystem module. So my application looks this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/users/:id', function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./userDb.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var users = json.users;

    console.log(users[0].id); // returns 1593

    console.log(req.params.id); // returns 1593

    var userObj = null;

    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      var currentUser = users[i];

      console.log(currentUser.id); // returns 1593

      if (currentUser.id === req.params.id) { // this should be fine 1593 === 1593
         userObj = currentUser;
         break;
      }
    }

    console.log(userObj); // returns undefined

    res.render('users', {
      user: userObj
     });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

The log will always return 1593, when I pass it as a parameter but when I want to render my handlebars template, the assigned object is null.

`userObj` is null, even when trying this code

```
var userObj = users.find(u => u.id === req.params.id);
```

but I think the database is not wrong. Where did I made a mistake =?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that `req.params.id` is a `String`. Try :

```
const userObj = users.find(u => u.id === Number(req.params.id));
```

---

When you have a doubt about it :

```
console.log(
       `First value : ${v1} - ${typeof v1}`,
       `Second value : ${v2} - ${typeof v2}`,
);
```

Comment: Just to add - other option could be non-strict(`==`) comparison

Comment: @codtex It will work yes :) But it's easier to understand if you comes back at the code later. Non strict comparaison and a good comment will be as good as the cast

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

```
 if (currentUser.id === req.params.id)
```

with

```
 if (currentUser.id == req.params.id)
```

Since req.params.id is a string  and  and currentUser.id is a number, they cannot be compared strictly .
 However a non-strict comparison should work fine.

Comment: If you go foir that soluce @Question3r remember to insert a comment for the next developper to know why it's here. Because it'll think you just forgot to use `===` which is a common mistake for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(userObj); // returns undefined
```

is called after the readFile callback, this is an [asynchronous non-blocking event](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm)!
You have to move your:

```
 res.render('users', {
      user: userObj
     });
```

at the end of readFile function